# How to Get Previous not null value

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a calculation sheet and I need to get previous not null value from table. I am not getting how I can get previous not null value. My table has some fields like userId, sale volume,  growth volume , Month.
Now user can enter one out of sale volume and growth volume and sale price and growth price. if user will not sale volume then he will enter the growth volume value and i need to get last not null sale volume to calculate growth rate on month basis.

This is my query to get not null growth volume field value:

```
$select= "SELECT * 
          FROM `tbl_revenue`   
          WHERE `price_currency_contract`=0 
          AND growth_rate_price!=0";
```

This calculation is working on month basis. like user will enter the sale volume for january, feb, march for all 12 months and if he is not entered the sale volume then he needs to enter growth volume  for this he need last not null sale volume entry.
Please help me  how i can find previous not null sale volume.

Comment: is all the inormation you need in one table ?
can you give us a example of the data structure ? (what is this (not)null values you mentioned).
what is the task you perform, what is the query about in the real world..

Comment: Previous to what? Previous to January 2013? (It's not clear whether you're even storing the year.)

Answer (score 0):

End the query with:

```
ORDER BY Month DESC
LIMIT 1
```